# Что означает "+" в выводе ls -l?

Tags: cygwin

Пример вывода `ls -l`

```
$ ls -l /etc/lighttpd/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 xxxx yyyy     0 Aug 15  2015 conf.d/
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 xxxx yyyy     0 Aug 15  2015 vhosts.d/
-rw-r--r--  1 xxxx yyyy 12416 Sep  2  2015 lighttpd.conf
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 xxxx yyyy  3234 Jan 13  2015 modules.conf*
```

Почему у некоторых файлов "плюс" есть, а у некоторых нет?

Нигде про это не встречал. Важность невелика, просто интересно, может, знает кто?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В линуксе этот '+' означает, что файл (или директория) имеет расширенный список прав доступа, называемый [ACL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACL). Я так думаю, что в случае с Windows это его собственный ACL, а не линуксовый.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Действительно, у плюсованных больше пользователей/групп в "Безопасности". Подозреваю, что это последствия `chmod` на локальной машине.